# Replace a row with zeros if one of its elements is higher than a fix number

Tags: r, if-statement, matrix, rows

I am doing the pricing of a Barrier option (if the underlying asset goes above 120, it cease to exist) in R using MC simulation.

Basically, I have a matrix (10000X100) that can have values raning from around 30 to 200 and I would like that if a value in a row goes above 120, all the values in this row will be set to 0.

I think people do it like that in MatLab but I can't do it in R:

```
nbrsim = 10000;
nbr_step = 100;
S = zeros(nbrsim,nbre_step+1);
    for j = 1:nbrsim
    if min(S(j,:)) <= B
       l(j) = 0;
    else
        l(j) = 1;
    end
    vectpayoffs(j) = l(j)*max(ST(j) - K,0);
    end
```

I will be very glad if someone knows how to do this computation

Comment: `values[apply(values > 120, 1, any), ] <- 0`

Comment: You solution is working perfectly fine, thank you very much !!

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job,

do rowsums of `matrix > 120`, if there's any value greater than 120, the sum will be greater than zero.

```
exMatrix <- matrix(rpois(10000,110),nrow = 100)

Contains120 <- rowSums(exMatrix > 120)

exMatrix[Contains120 > 0,] <- 0
```